# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word (await)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

guys. I'm using Google Firestore to save some data in a database. If, for example, I use the code provided by Google to replace or create a new document in the database, I get the error: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word*. I know the problem is that await can only be used with asynchronous functions, but these are not functions created by me. They are imported from the Firestore libraries and I'm using the code provided by Google. What is wrong here? Thank you.

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "LA"), {
  name: "Los Angeles",
  state: "CA",
  country: "USA"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The "await" only makes the rest of the code wait for the method to finish.
If you want to keep it:

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

(async function() {
  await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "LA"), {
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
  })
})();
```

If not:

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "LA"), {
  name: "Los Angeles",
  state: "CA",
  country: "USA"
});
```

Comment: I see your point, but it's very confusing, because the code was provided by Google as an example, and not only with the setDoc method, but with many others. If your point is true, why does Google use such a code? See here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=en

Comment: In the case of google it needs the await to guarantee that the functions are called one after the other